# ios uiAutomation tapWithOptions not working properly

Tags: ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have to run UIAutomation for touch and hold..
I am using tapWithoptions(offset,duration)..but the problem is i want to vary the cordinates
on which it will tap..but thats not happening..its always taking center cordinate for some
weird reason.

The same command works properly if i remove the duration parameter..but i want duration in it..following is the line i am using for it:-

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].scrollViews()[0].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:xPos, y:yPos},duration:1.2});

Any help in this regard shall be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had almost same issue. You ca try `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].scrollViews()[0].tapWithOptions({x: 27.0, y: 949.0}, {duration:3});`

If you see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/dragInsideWithOptions), tapOffset is not the exact x and y positions. It is just relatives values between 0 and 1. You have to calculate these relative values according to x, y positions.

Answer (score 0):

Tapping scrollviews is not working very well with UI Automation. The best solution is to recalculate the position into window position and tap `mainWindow`.